# debug(function) doesn't open debug environment on R Studio Server

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, rstudio-server

Whenever I try to debug a function, the debug environment is not complete, so to speak.

A simple reproducible example:

```
 function_to_debug <- function(x,y) {
  x = x*2
  y = y*2
  total = x+y
  return(total)
}
debug(function_to_debug)

function_to_debug(2,3)
```

Expected result: debug buttons appear on console and I can use shortcuts from the debug menu. I can also see the function parameters on the function environment and traceback. This runs on R Studio 4.1.2 on my machine.

[image: Expected]

Actual result: Although I can debug by pressing "enter" and go line by line, debug commands don't work. I can't click on them or use shortcuts. There's nothing in the function environment and no traceback. This runs on R version 4.0.1 (Server on work machine).

[image: Actual]

I don't understand why this is happening. I don't think it's a version problem since I used to debug things on my machine using R 4.0. Is this a server thing?

Comment: Is it possible you're evaluating the entire code block (function definition, debug(function), function call) at once?  If so - please try to evaluate the 3 statements (in particular the `debug` one) separately

Comment: Tried that too, but still doesn't work,

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce on RStudio server, but am seeing some problems when evaluating the entire code block together. What happens when you type (or paste) the statements manually, one by one, at the console?

Comment: Exactly the same thing as when I run the entire block at once.  The same thing happens with different peope from my organization, so I'm thiking it's a problem specific to our server. I just don´t even know where to look to try and change something.

Comment: Open an issue with rstudio directly:. In my experience they are friendly and helpful: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: Thank you! Will do and post a solution here if I get one.